# Minimum product spanning tree

Tags: java, c, algorithm, graphics, graph

In the `minimum product spanning tree` problem, the cost of a tree is the product of all the edge weights in the tree, instead of the sum of the weights. 
You may assume that all edges have positive weight. I would like to get answers for the following problems.

**(1)** Give a graph whose minimum product spanning tree is different than the minimum weight spanning tree.

**(2)** Give an efficient algorithm to compute the minimum product spanning tree. (Hint: think logarithms).

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Hints: a - thinks of a Special number. B - think montonicity

Comment: @VaughnCato I just don't even know where to begin. I am solving these to prepare for an interview, so this is NOT hw. I know how to find MST, but I am clueless about Minimum products

Comment: @collapsar doesn't help me

Comment: @user2304720. Any more specific hint to b actually means giving Out the Solution. Wrt a, try some. You only Need to find 1 example, Play around a Bit with some Sample Graphs.

Comment: `a*b*c = e^(log(a) + log(b) + log(c))`

Comment: @VaughnCato can you explain that please

Answer (score 1):

The problem of Minimum Product Spanning tree can be solved by converting the tree by taking the logarithm of edge weights and then finding the MST of this modified tree.

Remember the property of Logarithms, `log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)`. Thus the Minimum product spanning tree can be converted to an Minimum Cost Spanning Tree problem.